# wp_mail doesn't work when logged in?

Tags: ajax, jquery, javascript, wp-mail

I am having trouble with a wp_mail function I created, which sends an email when I press a button.
It does work great when you do this logged out. But as soon as I am logged in it stops working. It is not a capability issue, as I get the error as a Super Admin also.

Why would this happen?
I am using a PHP function together with Ajax to send the email, Javascript function is called onclick.

```
function searchEmail(email,title,content,location) {
  var admin_url = admin_ajax.ajaxurl;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: admin_url,
    datatype: "html",
    data: { 'action': 'search_notify_email', email: email, title: title, content: content, location: location },
    success: function() {
      searchNotification();
    },error:function() {
      searchNotificationError();
    }
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
function search_notify_email() {
  // Set variables
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  // Change Email to HTML
  add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_email_content_type' );
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Test subject!";
    $message = "<img src='favicon.png'><br><b>Test!</b>";
    if (empty($title)) {
      $message .= "<br><br><b>" . $_POST['content'] . "</b> test.<br> ";
    }
    else {
      $message .= "<br><br><b>" . $_POST['content'] . "</b> test " . $_POST['title'] . " test.<br> ";
    }
    if (!empty($location)) {
      $message .= "Test <b>" . $_POST['location'] . "</b>";
    }
    $headers[] = 'From: Testing <noreply@example.com>';

    if ( wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
      // Success
    } else {
      // Error
    }
    die();
    // Remove filter HTML content type
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_email_content_type' );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_notify_email', 'search_notify_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_search_notify_emaill', 'search_notify_email');

// Reset Email content type to standard text/html
function set_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo in the hook that runs for logged in users:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_search_notify_emaill', 'search_notify_email');
```

There's an extra `l` in the hook name. The hook names need to be the same, apart from `nopriv_`, so you should have:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_notify_email', 'search_notify_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_search_notify_email', 'search_notify_email');
```

When you send an AJAX request with an `action` WordPress runs the hook `wp_ajax_{$action}` (where `$action` is the parameter passed with the request) if you're logged in, or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` if the user is not logged in. Since you'd used an incorrect hook name for the logged-in version (due to the typo) your `search_notify_email()` function wasn't hooked to run when the user was logged in.

Comment: Oh, thank you for catching that! I am very glad it was something this simple. However without your help I would probably have spent many more hours debugging this!

Comment: I have another question, slightly related to this. It is the same function. The `content` is sent to the javascript onclik with this `echo get_the_content();` which works great. Except when there are multiple lines in the content, then nothing will happen. Why is that? `the_content` doesn't work.

Comment: I created a new thread for this error here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328749/get-the-content-if-it-contains-multiple-lines-it-results-in-syntaxerror